# What properties of a theme have influence on the specific widget?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Suppose we have `AppBarLayout` with `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"`.
Inside there's a Toolbar in which we want to change the text color.
Question: how to find out what attribute of the theme should be changed?

I used the stupid method of just trying and found out that it's

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

But what is the right method to determine the connection between property of a widget `titleTextColor` and property of a theme `textColorPrimary`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));` or create ToolbarStyle, for example:

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

And add theme to toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"/>
```

Comment: The question is not how to create theme, but HOW TO KNOW that theme's "textColorPrimary" responsible for changing widget's titleTextColor property?